# How to create Python Django WebApplication on Github?

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, github, web-applications

I have created a static website on github which i have hosted on it.
URL -> **http://playcart.tk/**
But now i want to create a __python django __ site on github.
I have much knowledge of python django, i have created some web application on my local computer using python.

how to create python django web application on github?

Comment: You can do that only with static html. Github cannot render serverside logic, etc for you.. You might want to look into some other app hosting service providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hosting service provider.
You can try heroku and set up a free account.

Comment: which is the free and best hosting site for python-django

Comment: Click on pricing and select the free option to get started